# Iterating through textbox controls in a panel C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, iteration

I have seen many others with similar problems but I cannot find the flaw in my logic here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a Panel which I have added numerous label and textbox controls to, ie:

```
myPanel.Controls.Add(txtBox);
```

These controls are created and added in a method called previous to the iteration method.

I want to iterate through each textbox and use its Text property as a parameter in another method but I am not having any luck. Here is my attempt to iterate:

```
public void updateQuestions()
{
    try
    {
        foreach (Control c in editQuestionsPanel.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox questionTextBox = (TextBox)c;

                string question = questionTextBox.Text;

                writeNewQuestionToTblQuestions(question);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that the controls are not in the Panel when I arrive at this updateQuestions() method. Here is the process involved:

A commandButton is clicked and the questions are read from a DB, for each question a method is called which adds 2 labels and a textbox to editQuestionsPanel.Controls. This panel is inside a PlaceHolder which is then made visible.

When a button inside the PlaceHolder is clicked, the updateQuestions() method is called and the editQuestionsPanel.Controls.Count = 1. As there are approx 12 questions in the DB it should be around 36. The one control inside the Panel is of type:

```
System.Web.UI.LiteralControl
```

It contains no controls.

I am sure that somwhere in the lifecycle the Panel's controls are being cleared but I do not know how to step thru the life cycle. I have a Page_load method which is called as soon as a button is clicked but once the button which calls updateQuestions() is clicked the editQuestionsPanel.Controls.Count is already back to 1 so it must be cleared before this but I do not know how to correct this...

Any help you can give to help me solve this would be greatly appreciated - its killing me!

Comment: What is it that is not working?

Comment: Your code works for me. Try creating an app that does just what you have outlined, and if it doesn't work, post the whole thing.

Comment: As a side note, you should use `as` instead of `is` here. Right now, you are casting the variable `c` twice. Try doing `TextBox questionTextBox = c as TextBox; if (questionTextBox != null) { ... }` This will avoid an unnecessary cast.

Comment: My bet is that you have a lifecycle problem, or that `myPanel` is not `editQuestionsPanel`. To diagnose lifecycle problems, attach a debugger and inspect the controls collection on your panel at various lifecycle events (OnInit, OnLoad, OnPreRender, OnRender, event handlers, etc.), paying special attention to when the controls collection gets cleared.

Comment: I think it it is a life cycle problem, the control count is 37 after they are added. How can I step through the stages.. How do I insert a breakpoint at the start of OnInit and step thru to see where it gets cleared?

Comment: Where are you creating the TextBoxes? Page Load? Also, where are you trying to read them from? A click event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add controls dynamically, you need to do that on *every* request - asp.net doesn't do that for you!

Add the controls in the Init or Load phase, then they *will* get populated with the postback values.

Answer (score 4):

This selects from collection controls only that which are of type TextBox.

(the same as `control is TextBox` or `(control as TextBox) != null`)

If controls are contained in `editQuestionsPanel.Controls`:

```
using System.Linq;

IEnumerable<TextBox> textBoxes = editQuestionsPanel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();    
foreach (TextBox textBox in textBoxes)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

To select all child controls use next extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetChildControls<T>(this Control control) where T : Control
{
    var children = control.Controls.OfType<T>();
    return children.SelectMany(c => GetChildControls<T>(c)).Concat(children);
}
```

Using:

```
IEnumerable<TextBox> textBoxes = editQuestionsPanel.GetChildControls<TextBox>();
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution - it is definately a better approach to reading the controls. However, this is of no use to me as the controls within editQuestionPanel.Controls seem to be getting cleared before it reaches my code. I have stepped through PreInit and Init using override methods. When the controls are all in place in the panel, the Save button is clicked - At the PreInit stage the editQuestionsControls.Count = null and at the Init stage it is 1. It should be 37. How do I stop the controls from being cleared?

Comment: @Frank: I think you need to investigate/debug your code more to find a place where panel drops its child control. I'm sure it happens somewhere programmatically

Comment: @Frank: One more complex solution - replace panel with your one where you will override type of collection holding child controls, just to debug `Collection.Controls.Add/Remove/Clear`

Comment: I just stepped through the page, testing editQuestionPanel.Controls.Count at each meaningful step. The controls are added and I get a value of 37 right up to the end of my override OnUnload() method. Then once I click the Save button to start iterating thru the controls, on the OnInit() method I get a value of null. So the controls must be being cleared after the Unload stage. I'm sorry but I did not full understand ur solution in the above comment - will it help me?

Comment: @Frank: Oops, sorry, some moment I thought that you're talking about WinForms controls. So when you're using ASP.NET it's the normal behavior of UpdatePanel to drop its child controls, I guess

Comment: I am not using an UpdatePanel - simply an ordinary Panel. If that makes a difference..

Answer (score 1):

A frequently made mistake: `Container.Controls` only contains the first level child controls in this container. That is: TextBox1 in PanelA, PanelA in PanelB, you can't get TextBox1 in PanelB.Controls.

My solution is to write an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> AllControls(this Control ctl)
{
   List<Control> collection = new List<Control>();
   if (ctl.HasControls())
   {
       foreach (Control c in ctl.Controls)
       {
             collection.Add(c);
             collection = collection.Concat(c.AllControls()).ToList();
       }
   }
   return collection;
}
```

Now TextBox1 is in `PanelB.AllControls()`. To filter all controls with type, using `PanelB.AllControls().OfType<TextBox>()`

Comment: You're right but using LINQ you can do the same much easier. See my post

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this instead:

```
var questions = from tb in editQuestionsPanel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                select tb.Text;

foreach(var question in questions)
{
    writeNewQuestionToTblQuestions(question);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the other answers don't help, try doing your code but add recursivity. Your code would not work if it's editQuestionsPanel => Panel => Textbox

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        int Count = 0;
        foreach (Control ctr in Panel1.Controls)
        {
            if (ctr is TextBox)
                Count++;
        }
```